# Get Configurable Products Under Specific Category REST API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to get configurable products only under specific category using

> `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=configurable&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=26`

But the result is not correct.

Is there is something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey it should be more like

```
/rest/V1/products
?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=10201
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=type_id
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=configurable
searchCriteria[current_page]=1
searchCriteria[page_size]=26
```

just heads up the `[condition_type]=eq` is optional as it is the default